# Scraping page with BeautifulSoup gives strange results (multiple </p> at the end). Why?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page with BeautifulSoup. I would like to keep `<p></p>` tags to later store the content in .xml files, divided into paragraphs, headers, etc. Unfortunately, the result is a bit surprising to me. Here is how it lookslike:

[image]

Why is so many `</p></p>` at the end? I got used to the structure that looks rather like this:

```
<p>some paragraph... </p>
<p>next paragraph... </p>
```

Not like this:

```
some paragraph... <p>
next paragraph... <p></p>
</p>
```

When I examine the HTML structure in Chrome, everything looks fine:

[image]

Why is this happening?
Here is my code:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
'username': os.environ['POLITYKA_USERNAME'],
'password': os.environ['POLITYKA_PASSWORD'],
'login_success': 'http://archiwum.polityka.pl',
'login_error': 'https://archiwum.polityka.pl/art/grypa-nam 
niestraszna,378836.html'
}

login_url = 'https://www.polityka.pl/sso/login'
base_url = 'http://archiwum.polityka.pl'
example_url = 'https://archiwum.polityka.pl/art/sciganie- 
wnbsp;organach,378798.html'
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    post = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
    request = session.get(example_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
    box = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'container'}).find('div', {'class' : 'middle'}).find('div', {'class', 'right'}).find('div', {'class' : 'box'})
    content = box.find('p', {'class' : 'box_text'}).find_next_sibling()
    print(content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extraction from [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

> Another alternative is the pure-Python html5lib parser, which parses HTML the way a web browser does. Depending on your setup, you might install html5lib with one of these commands:

```
$ apt-get install python-html5lib

$ easy_install html5lib

$ pip install html5lib
```

with that being said, you need to **still** use plural form of `find_next_siblings()`

Also, you will need a parameter to your `find_next_siblings()` function.

example:

```
get_html = 'https://archiwum.polityka.pl/art/sciganiewnbsp;organach,378798.html'
soup = bs4(get_html, 'html5lib')
find_location = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'container'}) \
                    .find('div', {'class' : 'middle'}) \
                    .find('div', {'class', 'right'}) \
                    .find('div', {'class' : 'box'}) \
                    .find('p', {'class' : 'box_text'}) \
                    .find_next_siblings('p')

for content in find_location:
    print(content)
```

Simply change `'html.parser'` to `'html5lib'` and `find_next_siblings('p')` then iterate the `list()`

better still, add a conditional statement to remove empty tags

```
for content in find_location:
    if content.get_text() is not '':
        print(content)
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The result is converted into a list, but everything looks exactly the same.

Comment: after some time trying out and researching, I found that using another parser work almost perfectly. do try it again.

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you!